# Поиск всех циклов в ориентированном графе методом обхода в глубину

Tags: c++, графы, dfs

Я написал программу поиска всех циклов в ориентированном графе и их количества методом поиска в глубину. Граф задаётся списком рёбер. Но эта программа работает не совсем верно.(Граф и что получилось на изображениях) Уважаемые программисты, может кто помочь с данной проблемой?`

```
int from = 0, n = 0, k = 0,ncycle=0, to;

void DFS(int v){
    color[v]=1;
    for (int i=0; i<nreber; i++){
        if(g[i][0]==v){
            to = g[i][1];
            if( color[to]==0){
                p[n][0]=g[i][0];
                p[n][1]=g[i][1];
                from=v;
                n++;
                DFS(to);
            }
            else if (color[to]=1){
                p[n][0]=g[i][0];
                p[n][1]=g[i][1];
                k=n;
                cout<<ncycle+1<<") ";
                for(int i=0; i<k;i++)
                    cout << p[i][0] << '-'<< p[i][1] << ' ';

                cout << p[k][0] << '-' << p[k][1] << ' ' << endl;
                ncycle++;
            }
        color[v]=2;
        }   
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, все циклы можно получить примерно так (псевдокод):

```
dfs(v, v_start):  
    if (visited[v]):  
        if (v == v_start):  
            вывести цикл
        return

   visited[v] = 1  
   for neighbor in adjlist[v]:  
       dfs(neighbor, v_start )
   visited[v] = 0

for v in vertices:
   dfs(v, v) 
   remove(v)
```

P.S. Пишут, что алгоритм Johnson эффективен (и в Python networkx.simple_cycles он используется)

Comment: Я вроде и понимаю реализацию алгоритма, у меня именно проблемы с выводом. В моём решении необходимо использовать DFS.